# Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound

Tags: neo4j

While executing algorithm I am getting this error -

```
There is no procedure with the name algo.shortestPath registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

I checked for solutions for this problem almost all are suggesting to update conf file to make procedures unrestriceted. I have added these configuration -

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*, algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*, algo.*
```

I have also copied all jar files from lib to plugin folder where neo4j-graph-algo-3.4.17.jar is available.
But still after restarting, I am getting same error.

Comment: Can you run `CALL dbms.procedures() YIELD name WHERE name CONTAINS 'shortest' RETURN *` on your database and see if you get anything?

Comment: Thanks that worked.But why did CALL algo.list() not work? Is that command deprecated?